# How to simulate a incoming call using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, simulate, incoming-call

I want to simulate a incoming call in Xamarin Forms app and capture the answered vs cancelled action by user. I want to initiate the call on a trigger like timer in the background.

Comment: This is not a feature of Forms, but from the emulators you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As Gerald said in his comment, this is not a `Xamarin.Forms` feature. You can achieve this in the emulators, for example in the Android emulator, go to the settings into the **phone** tab. Right there you can simulate a phone call and SMS:

[image]